# Copy and paste without unlocking the protection in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, cell-format

I protected certain cells in the excel worksheet without editing (Using review> Protected sheet) but when I copy the worksheet, locked cells turn into unlocked cells and password is removed.

I want to copy the worksheet in the same workbook into different sheets as well as  I want to keep the password without unlocking the cells (editing) even after copying the worksheet. Can I do that Masters???

Comment: Can you just set the two ranges equal? `Range([destination range]).Value = Range([original data range]).Value`

Comment: Please explain how you 'copy the worksheet'. Protection should be preserved if you copy the entire sheet correctly

Comment: Ctrl+A >>>> Ctrl+C >>>> create new sheet >>>> Ctrl+V

Answer (score -1):

There is more than one way to copy.

- If you use copy and paste for a group of cells, then the protection will not come across.
- If you right click the tab with the sheet name and select copy, you can copy the entire sheet to another workbook or make another sheet inside the current workbook. This case does preserve the protection meaning it is there and with the original password.

Comment: the real problem is I'm not the person who use this after I make this... but I don't now who will. normally people select the entire sheet ( ctrl+A) and copy it. then make the new sheet and press Ctrl+V. in that case protection will disappear. Any way Thank you for giving a new idea.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this,
1. Copy the cell locked/Protected sheet. 
2. Paste on the next sheet or whatever the sheet you want. 
3. Right-click the tab button.
4. And hit the "protect sheet" option.
5. Bingo! You will find the cells protected as same in the source sheet.

Thank you,

[how to keep on the protection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtajn.png)